# How to write tasklist in typora?

Tags: markdown

I got some problem when i tried to write markdown in typora, which can render text immediaetly. In typora's markdown style, with '-' at the beginning of a line it can render a list and with '- []' or '-[x]' it can render a tasklist complete or incomplete. However, everytime I tried to write '- []', typora always detects the character '-' and renders a list instead of a tasklist. Is there any solution? Thanks!

Comment: Task lists are non-standard Markdown. Are you sure that typora supports them? It's not clear from your question if you are asking if they are supported, or if you know that they are supported, but are unsure of the proper syntax to get them to work.

Comment: @Waylan Yes. Typora did support tasklist. In their official website http://support.typora.io/Markdown-Reference/ you can fand how to write tasklist, however it doesn't work for me

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [typora's website](http://support.typora.io/Markdown-Reference/#task-list):

> Task lists are lists with items marked as either [ ] or [x] (incomplete or complete).

They even provide an example:

```
- [ ] a task list item
- [ ] list syntax required
- [ ] normal **formatting**, @mentions, #1234 refs
- [ ] incomplete
- [x] completed
```

Just tried it in version 0.9.9.8.2 on macOS and it worked right away.

The spaces around and between `[` and `]` are required for this to work.

Comment: Yes. But I failed on windows 8.1 with the latest version. As '-' can render unorder list, everytime I tried it rendedr as a unorder list followed with '[ ]'

Comment: Hmm... have you tried changing to source code mode (main menu > View), type the list's markdown and change back to normal mode?

Comment: ok. I just found it work when I type in a space after ]. Thanks! I can't believe that I never try to type in a space before...